# Symfony2: Validating Forms/Entitys in different Levels

Tags: forms, symfony, validation

I allow Users that have nothing more than username/email/password.
But if they want to access certain areas, i need more information and present a form to them.
Now i want to validate this form, but whatever data is sent, it is valid since the entity is allowed to only have three basic attributes.

Simply checking for the desired fields needed to access a certain area is fairly easy, but communicating missing fields to the form is more complicated.
I'd have to match the fields to the form elements, add custom error messages and so forth.

Is there a best practive for my Problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read up on [*Validation Groups*](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validation-groups) — that's what you need.